# Make implementation of virtuals also virtual?

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

When implementing a pure virtual function in C++, is there a best-practices guideline that says the implementation should also be made virtual? What is the rationale?

```
class Interface
{
  public:
    virtual void foobar() = 0;
};

class Concrete
    : public Interface
{
  public:
    virtual void foobar();
};
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It does not matter.

`void foobar()` in `Concrete` is `virtual` regardless whether you declare it as such and it overrides the `void foobar()` in `Interface`.

Comment: I didn't know that virtual functions always remain virtual. I learned something about C++ today. :D

Comment: Didn't know that. I thought you have to tell it to remain virtual. What a pity, it could save the compiler from a virtual function call if he knows that he has a `Concrete` object.

Comment: If you're calling a foobar() through an Interface pointer then the compiler is forced to make a virtual function call since it has no way of knowing the actual type of the object. However, if you call foobar() on a Concrete object directly, the compiler is free to generate a direct call to the function rather than going through the vtable.

Comment: @Ferrucio: Just to make your comment a bit more clear - since a concrete class can be a base class in C++, what you describe is only possible when the context is complete enough for the compiler to decide that the concrete instance isn't actually used polymorphically.

Answer (score 7):

Although it doesn't matter if the `virtual` keyword is present in a derived class or not, I've found it to be an indispensable time-saving self-documenting practice to **always** include it, so that anyone working with your code a two years from now immediately can see that there is more to the class than what immediately meets the eye.

Comment: I believe this is actually one of the rules you can [optionally] tell the compiler to enforce in C++11, so if you ever forget your code won't compile.

Comment: @Dennis: I guess you're thinking of **Explicit virtual function overrides**: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Explicit_virtual_function_overrides